# How to select top N columns in a dataframe with a criteria

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my dataframe, it has high dimensionality (big number of columns) more than 10000 columns

The columns in my data are split into 3 categories

columns start with "Basic"
columns end with "_T"
and everything else

a sample of my dataframe is this

```
RowID   Basic1011 Basic2837 Lemon836 Car92_T Manf3953 Brat82 Basic383_T Jot112 ...
1       2         8         4        3       1        5      6          7
2       8         3         5        0       9        7      0          5
```

I want to have in my dataframe all "Basic" & "_T" columns and only TOP N (variable could be 3, 5, 10, 100, etc) of other columns

I have this code to give me top N for all columns. but what I am looking for just the top N for columns are not "Basic" or "_T"

and by Top I mean the greatest values

```
Top = 20
df = df.where(df.apply(lambda x: x.eq(x.nlargest(Top)), axis=1), 0)
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by top?

Comment: @DaniMesejo by Top I mean the greatest values

Comment: How to do you compare a column to another column?

Comment: @DaniMesejo by its value

Comment: A column is not greater (or lower than other column) what sorting criteria are you using?

Comment: See if you require any further clarification from the answers below. If no more question, let us know any of the answers best fit for your needs by accepting the answer you choose. Please also consider upvoting answer(s) helpful to you (including answer that you accept). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1: You can use [`.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with regex to filter the columns with the following 2 conditions:**

1. start with "Basic", **or**
2. end with "_T"

The **regex** used is `r'(?:^Basic)|(?:_T$)'` where:

`(?:   )`  is a non-capturing group of regex. It is for a temporary grouping.

`^`    is the start of text anchor to indicate start position of text

`Basic` matches with the text `Basic` (together with `^`, this `Basic` must be at the beginning of column label)

`|`  is the regex meta-character for `or`

`_T` matches the text `_T`

`$`  is the end of text anchor to indicate end of text position (together with `_T`, `_T$` indicate `_T` at the end of column name.

We name these columns as `cols_Basic_T`

**Step 2: Then, use [`Index.difference()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) to find others columns. We name these other columns as `cols_others`.**

**Step 3: Then, we apply the similar code you used to give you top N for all columns on these selected columns `col_others`.**

**Full set of codes:**

```
## Step 1
cols_Basic_T = df.filter(regex=r'(?:^Basic)|(?:_T$)').columns

## Step 2
cols_others = df.columns.difference(cols_Basic_T)

## Step 3
#Top = 20 
Top = 3     # use fewer columns here for smaller sample data here
df_others = df[cols_others].where(df[cols_others].apply(lambda x: x.eq(x.nlargest(Top)), axis=1), 0)
# To keep the original column sequence
df_others = df_others[df.columns.intersection(cols_others)]
```

**Results:**

**cols_Basic_T**

```
print(cols_Basic_T)

Index(['Basic1011', 'Basic2837', 'Car92_T', 'Basic383_T'], dtype='object')
```

**cols_others**

```
print(cols_others)

Index(['Brat82', 'Jot112', 'Lemon836', 'Manf3953', 'RowID'], dtype='object')
```

**df_others**

```
print(df_others)

## With Top 3 shown as non-zeros. Other non-Top3 masked as zeros

   RowID  Lemon836  Manf3953  Brat82  Jot112
0      0         4         0       5       7
1      0         0         9       7       5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, you may have to play around with column selection on outset to be sure you're filtering correctly.

```
# this gives you column names with Basic or _T anywhere in the column name.
unwanted = df.filter(regex='Basic|_T').columns.tolist()

# the tilda takes the opposite of the criteria, so no Basic or _T
dfn = df[df.columns[~df.columns.isin(unwanted)]]

#apply your filter
Top = 2
df_ranked = dfn.where(dfn.apply(lambda x: x.eq(x.nlargest(Top)), axis=1), 0)

#then merge dfn with df_ranked
```